# Error while using Yahoo PlaceFinder API and jQuery in json format

Tags: jquery, json, api, yahoo

I'm implementing some Yahoo API in one of my projects. I was using the Yahoo GeoPlanet in json format with jQuery and went really smooth. However I cannot get working the Yahoo PlaceFinder API with jQuery in json format.

When I do the request with the $.getJSON function I get the following message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=Vancouver&flags=J&count=10&lang=en&appid=MYKEY. Origin "http://yrm" is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Where "http://yrm" is my localhost servername for that project.

Below you'll find the code I'm using:

```
var url = 'http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=Vancouver&flags=J&count=10&lang=en&appid=' + yahooApiKey;

$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    console.dir(data);
});
```

The console.dir only prints NULL in the console.

Any idea on what can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
&callback=?
```

at the end of the url string